# LINQ to Entities Table top 100 with using distinct name

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I am having trouble finding up-to-date answers for using lambda expressions and order a list containing table data from an entity to be sorted by "likes" with no duplicate "agency" and only show Top 100.

I have the following, but it doesn't work for distinct I'm guessing. Everytime I run it and check it, it still has duplicate agency names appear. I have no clue why it's not taking care of duplicate agency names.

```
        public PartialViewResult Top100()
    {
        List<New_NYC_Usage_Table> data = db.New_NYC_Usage_Table.ToList();

        data = db.New_NYC_Usage_Table.Where(x => x.Platform != "TOTAL").ToList();
        data = data.OrderByDescending(x => x.Agency).Distinct().ToList();
        data = data.OrderByDescending(x => x.Likes_Follows_Etc).Take(100).ToList();
        return PartialView("_Data", data);

    }
```

If I'm unclear or this post is irrelevant or is a duplicate topic please point me to the right direction or a MSDN link or reference with helpful examples, thank you.

Comment: `Distinct()` only accounts two identical rows. What do you expect to happen when there are multiple rows with the same `Agency`, take the first row?

Comment: Don't use `.ToList()` each time, you only need it on the second last line. You are unnecessarily iterating the entire list each time you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to get a list of the top 100 agencies ordered by likes, follows etc BUT if an agency is in that list twice I am assuming that you only want the highest ranked showing, not both.

I think this linq query should do what you want (although I've only been able to test it on a similar table so be sure to check it carefully)

```
var data = db.New_NYC_Usage_Table.Where(x => x.Platform != "TOTAL")
.GroupBy(x => x.Agency, (key, g) => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Likes_Follows_Etc).First()).OrderByDescending(x => x.Likes_Follows_Etc).Take(100).ToList();
```

Here is whats happening. I'm getting all the records where the platform is not "TOTAL", then grouping them by agency. In each group I then get the highest likes so that I only have a single agency in each group. I then order these records by likes and finally take the top 100.

I notice in your code you always call .toList after each query, this is often not required and usually harms performance. You should only call to list at the last possible moment. your linq expressions aren't actually the collections of data but rather an instruction of what you want, you can keep adding to this instruction (like you do in your code but without the ".toList") and it won't actually go and get the data, only when you actually try to look at the data does it finally go and get it for you making it very efficient. every time you call .toList you are asking for your data to be evaluated but at that point you don't care what's there, you only care whats in your return result.

Comment: Hi Mark_H, thank you so much, the code work, but instead of using First() I changed it to FirstorDefault() due to an instance error and it can only be used as the final query. ^_^